# google map error when add marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I wan't to add marker in google map, where the latitude and longitude I get from database..

and this code for get data from database and add marker

```
public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str.toString();
    }


private void WC(final String alamat) {
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PetaActivity.this);
                myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                myProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                myProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String text = null;
                String urlwc = alamat;
                try {
                    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(urlwc));
                    if (data.length() != 0) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map;

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("id_jalan", c.getString("id_jalan"));
                            map.put("nama_jalan", c.getString("nama_jalan"));
                            map.put("latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
                            map.put("longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
                            map.put("foto", c.getString("foto"));
                            MyArrListMarker.add(map);
                            //end add marker

                            publishProgress((int) (i));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    text = e.getMessage();
                }
                //
                return text;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("WC Umum")
                        .snippet("24 Jam")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.toilet))
                        .position(new LatLng(
                                Double.parseDouble(MyArrListMarker.get(progress[0]).get("latitude")),
                                Double.parseDouble(MyArrListMarker.get(progress[0]).get("longitude"))))
                );
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();

                if (result != null) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PetaActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Koneksi Gagal");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Silahkan coba lagi");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "TUTUP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(alamat);
    }
```

but I get error when add marker, but if the marker I remove it's no error

this the logcat

```
 12:36:26.356 31593-31593/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method lq.b
12-29 12:36:27.276 31593-31593/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak, PID: 31593
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                           at lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak.PetaActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(PetaActivity.java:378)
                                                                                           at lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak.PetaActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(PetaActivity.java:334)
                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:648)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 12:36:28.776 31593-31864/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9.apk", zip file "/data/data/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak/code_cache/secondary-dexes/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: could you provide the code related to this line? Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method lq.b

Answer (score 0):

You `logcat`'s last line

> E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9.apk", zip file "/data/data/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak/code_cache/secondary-dexes/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/lapor.jalan.rusak.com.laporjalanrusak-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

says `ClassNotFoundException` that means you do not have the class. It is because you may not added the `lib dependency` or it is being removed at runtime.